# Response header name 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin ' contains invalid characters, aborting request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, heroku, laravel-middleware, laravel-5.7

I have a laravel app (deployed on heroku) where I am receiving a `500 Internal Server error`.

When I checked my logs, I get the error metheod in the title:

> Response header name 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin ' contains invalid characters, aborting request

I have a `cors middleware` with the following code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Content-type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');
    return $next($request);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe the problem is extra space before `:`

But in fact you should modify your middleware to do it in "Laravel way". Instead of

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers : Content-type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');
return $next($request);
```

you should use:

```
return $next($request)
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
      ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, Origin');
```

Comment: Worked a treat! Thanks